# Not able to send the mail through powershell script

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

Below is the code:

```
$TLS12Protocol = [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType] 'Tls12'
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = $TLS12Protocol
$smtpencryption = 'tls'
$From = "JIT.Batch@duckcreek.com"
$To = "abhishek.chawla@duckcreek.com”
$recipients = "<abhishek.chawla@duckcreek.com>"
[string[]]$To = $recipients.Split(',')
$Cc = "abhishek.chawla@duckcreek.com"
$Subject = "JITAppointment batch Started on StateAuto Production"
$Body = "JITAppointment batch Started on SA Production for latest file"
$SMTPServer = "smtp.office365.com"
$SMTPPort = "587"
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString "*******" -AsPlainText -Force
$mycreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($from, $secpasswd)
Send-MailMessage -From $From -to $To -Cc $Cc -Subject $Subject -Body $Body -BodyAsHtml -SmtpServer $SMTPServer -Port $SMTPPort -UseSsl -Credential $mycreds
#Send-MailMessage -From $From -to $To -Cc $Cc -Subject $Subject -Body $Body -SmtpServer $SMTPServer
```

and i am getting below error when i run this on server:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QlabF.png)

I wont be able to send the mail through this code.

Comment: The picture you've uploaded appears to be a blank white screen

Comment: Please [edit] your question and insert the error message in full as [formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Answer (score 0):

I can see you're sending via smtp.office365.com. Microsoft 365 no longer supports basic authentication which means you cannot use `Send-MailMessage`. Alternatives include `Send-MgUserMail` which is part of Module [Microsoft.Graph.Users.Actions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.graph.users.actions/?view=graph-powershell-1.0)

Comment: Getting another error

`Send-MgUserMail : The term 'Send-MgUserMail' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling 
of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:15 char:1
+ Send-MgUserMail -From $From -to $To -Cc $Cc -Subject $Subject -Body $ ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Send-MgUserMail:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
`